# Is the following sentence grammatically incorrect? If so why?

Tags: ellipsis

> No, impossible. Could someone I barely knew, know so much about me?

Is this sentence gramatically incorrect? If so, what would be the correct version? (While maintaining more or less the same structure?)

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: @Jasper I wrote it myself.

Comment: It is grammatical, but perhaps not perfectly idiomatic. It depends on the meaning you wish to convey. "No, impossible" would be followed by an exclamation ("How could....!") whereas you've asked a question ("Could...?").   If you mean to suggest that the speaker is having doubts about the first statement ("No, impossible.") then a question is fine. Or if the question is a "rhetorical" question, one which asks the listener to consider the possibility, then a question is also OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one minor correction, I can imagine reading something similar in a contemporary novel, or hearing something similar in a movie or television show.  The context would be a teenage girl or young woman talking to herself about the weird situation she has found herself in.

> No, impossible.  How could someone I barely knew, know so much about me?

The first example "sentence" is not a complete sentence.  It is short for something like "No, this situation had to be impossible."

The example question is a complete question.  It is short for either
"How could someone I barely knew know so much about me?" or "Was it possible for someone I barely knew to know so much about me?"

The complete example is short for something like:

> No, this situation was impossible.
>    Was it possible for someone I barely knew to know so much about me?
>    Of course not.